# Does facebook open graph's fb:explicitly_shared require approval even for developer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

fb:explicitly_shared=true, image[0][user_generated]=true, I expected the action to display with a full size image in timeline and a small story in activity feed.  Instead, I get only the small (with the smallest thumbnail possible) in the activity feed.  Nothing in timeline.

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/#publishing) is unclear.  Documentation states regarding user_generated:

> While it might seem appealing to always use user_generated photos, there are some criteria that must be met in order to maintain a good user experience, and for your app to get approved for the capability to be used by people who are not developers or testers of the app

This does not specify whether 1) The POST to /me/namespace:action will succeed without error for the developers but still not display in the timeline or 2) The POST to /me/namespace:action should behave in every way as if "User Generated" was approved (for posts on behalf of the developers)

I have the same question about **fb:explicitly_shared**.  Cannot determine whether behavior is unexpected because expected behavior isn't clear in documentation.

Following all examples documented with variations on what is in the meta tags and the data posted to /me/namespace:action there is simply no way for me to get anything to show up in the timeline (aside from posting directly to feed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not test any of these things with the Graph API Explorer.  The Graph API Explorer appears to be partially sandboxed in it's own special way.